# узнать email по ssl-сертификату домена Let's Encrypt

Tags: ssl, letsencrypt

Создал для своего домена ssl-сертификат Let's Encrypt (панель VestaCP делает это автоматически). Теперь мучает вопрос: можно ли узнать мой email по зарегистрированному сертификату? Как это сделать? Поисковики смогут его увидеть?

Comment: Разве в сертификате есть поле для e-mail?

Comment: при ручном получении сертификата cerbot-ом, запрашивается согласие на shared email.